# Disable right click on vimeo player

Tags: jquery, html

I have 'iframe' tag -

```
<iframe id="vdDisabled" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I tried all jquery methods include

```
$('iframe').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {return false;});
$('iframe').mousedown(function(e){ });
```

to disable right click but none of them helped me. Any one have idea how to do that

Comment: [Some reading](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#summary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

Added an async function to synchronously run:

> ```
> $('figcaption').css('z-index','0')
> ```

and then:

> ```
> $('figcaption').css('z-index','1')
> ```

The mousedown event was added and a `switch()` to control each mouse button.

---

### Use an Overlay

Wrap the iframe in a block element with another block element. Make the iframe and its sibling element `position:absolute` and the parent `position:relative`. Then make the sibling `z-index` at least 1 more than the iframe. Then use the following:

> `$(`**sibling element**`).on("contextmenu", function(e) { return false; });`

There is some extra styling involved as well, review the demo. Note, there are some minor modifications to the iframe as well.

---

### Demo

```js
/*
This async function will synchronously control the click events
from happening asynchonously. Normally a timeout will finish 
earlier.
*/
async function clickControl() {
  const noClick = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve($('figcaption').css('z-index', '1')), 1500);
    });
  }
  await noClick();
}

/*
Delegate contextmenu and mousedown on figcaption. The switch will
determine what to do when the left, middle, or right mouse button
is clicked.
*/
$("figcaption").on("contextmenu mousedown", function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 1: // Left
      $('figcaption').css('z-index', '0');
      break;
    case 2: // Middle
      break;
    case 3: // Right
      return false;
    default:
      break;
  }
  // Calling async function will wait for switch to finish
  clickControl();
});
```

```css
/* Parent Wrapper Element */

figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
  /* For responsive video */
  /* padding-bottom: 56.25%;*/
  /* padding-top: 25px; */
  /* height: 0; */
}


/* Sibling Overlay Element */

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
  <iframe id="vdDisabled" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</figure>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne for reply. This code will also disable the play/pause and other controls in player which is not required.

Comment: Oops I forgot about that, standby.

Comment: This is closer to what i want..Thanks @zer00ne. But while playing it is a bit late to play the vimeo video...

Comment: Try adjusting the time 1500ms in this line: `setTimeout(() => resolve($('figcaption').css('z-index', '1')),` **1500** `);` I did this on my phone and it's slow in certain areas.